# union of convex sets is convex implies what?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, convex-analysis

I would like some help on the following question.

Let  $a,b \in \mathbb{R}^k$. Given $\overline{B}(a,1)\bigcup B(b,2) $ is convex.

Does it implies one of the following?

1. $k=1$ or $|a-b|\leq1$
2. $k=1$ or $|a-b| < 1$
3. $|a-b|\leq1$
4. $k=1$

I was able to show that it doesn't necessarily implies 3 and 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drawing pictures helps a lot. As the questions indicate, there is a difference between $k = 1$ and $k \geq 2$.
Call $B = \overline B(a, 1) \cup B(b, 2)$.

4$.$ If $k = 2$, $a = b$, then $\overline B(a, 1) \cup B(b, 2) = B(b, 2)$ is convex. So 4) is not implied.

3$.$ If $k = 1$ and $a = 0$ and $ b = 2$, then $\overline B(a, 1) \cup B(b, 2) = [-1, 1] \cup (0, 4) = [-1, 4)$ is convex. So 3) is not implied.

In two (or more) dimensions if the smaller ball does not lie in the bigger one, you generally can find a "dent" where the boundaries intersect.
So the interesting case is when $B(a, 1) \subset B(b,2)$ but $\overline B(a, 1) \not\subset B(b,2)$:

2$.$ If $k = 2$, $a = (0,0)$, $b = (1,0)$, then $z := (-1, 0) \in \overline B(a, 1) \setminus B(b, 2)$.
First check that this is the only point. Let $p = (x, y) \in \overline B((0,0), 1)$: $x^2 + y^2 \leq 1$. In particular $-1 \leq x \leq 1$.
Then $|p - b|^2 = (x-1)^2 + y^2 = x^2 + y^2 + 1 - 2x \leq 1+1-2x \leq 2 - 2(-1) = 4 = 2^2$ where the last estimate holds equal if and only if $x = -1$ which means $y= 0$ and $p = z$.

So, if we consider any two points in $B$ that are not $z$, then they are both in $B(b,2)$ and hence their connecting line is in $B(b,2)$, so in $B$.

Now take any $q = (x, y) \in \overline B(a, 1) \cup B(b, 2) \setminus \{z\} = B(b, 2)$ and consider any point on the connecting line:
$(1-λ)q + λz = ((1-λ)x + λ(-1), (1-λ)y)$. It's distance to $b$ is
$$
\begin{align}
|(λx + (1-λ)(-1), λy) - (1, 0)|^2
&= (λx -2 + λ)^2 + (λy)^2 \\
&= λ^2x^2 + λ^2 + 4 - 4λx - 4λ + 2λ^2x + λ^2y^2 \\
&< 4 + λ^2 + λ^2 - 4λx - 4λ + 2 λ^2 x \\
&= 4 + 2λ(λ - 2x - 2 + λx) \\
&= 4 + 2\underbrace{λ}_{> 0}\underbrace{(λ-2)}_{<0}\underbrace{(1 + x)}_{>0} \\
&< 4 \\
\implies (1-λ)q + λz &\in B(b, 2)
\end{align}
$$
Therefore 2) is not implied.

1$.$ is indeed implied. Note that we can rotate and translate the coordinate system so that $a = (0, ..., 0)$ and $b = (|b-a|, 0, ..., 0)$.
Then you can be sure that your drawing actually covers all cases.